# Setting a variable to reference another variable

Tags: python

```
DS1 = 89.3923
Label = "DS1"
LabelValue = Label
print(LabelValue)
```

I'm stuck on something, I have some calculations which determines the value for "Label" in the case above, it's DS1. I want to return the actual value contained in DS1 when printing LabelValue so the print should result in 89.3923 rather than DS1.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

First this is generally a bad idea and you should instead use a dictionary like this:

```py
d = {"DS1": 89.3923}
Label = d["DS1"]
LabelValue = Label
print(LabelValue)
```

But if you really don't want to you can look it up in `locals`.

```py
DS1 = 89.3923
Label = locals()["DS1"]
LabelValue = Label
print(LabelValue)
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples @RedKnite , I will try and clean things up to use a dictionary